# Illegal instructions (core dumped) while importing Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, ubuntu-18.04, tensorflow2.0

I ve tried to install Tensorflow.
But while importing as
import tensorflow as tf

it says Illegal instruction( core dumped).
Tried using both Tensorflow 1.5 and Tensorflow 2.1
Nothing worked.

Comment: Tensorflow can be built with support for the SSE and AVX instruction sets for performance gains, however not all CPUs support these instructions, particularly on older machines. I would expect a default version not to include these instructions for maximum support, but perhaps your package manager/distribution include an optimized version with these instructions, which your machine can't run.
You might want to check if your CPU make/model supports AVX. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24548

Comment: Can I download the trained model from colab to my system?? and load only the trained model within my system without importing Tensorflow again??? If yes, how how can I do that?? I ve tried using pickle but came to know tensorflow trained model cannot be saved using pickle...

Comment: Installed Tensorflow using Anaconda Navigator... It's now solved